# Create simple functions with dependent types

Tags: idris

I am learning from [the official documentation](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#first-class-types). I have tried to modify the first example:

```
isSingleton : Bool -> Type
isSingleton True = Nat
isSingleton False = List Nat

mkSingle : (x : Bool) -> isSingleton x
mkSingle True = 0
mkSingle False = []
```

Here are my tries:

```
compute_type : Integer  -> Type
compute_type 1 = Nat
compute_type 2 = String

--foo : (x : Integer) -> compute_type x
-- foo 1     = Z
-- foo 2 = ?one --unwords ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Error:

```
{-
first_class_type.idr:7:13:
  |
7 | foo 1     = Z
  |             ^
When checking right hand side of foo with expected type
        compute_type 1

Type mismatch between
        Nat (Type of 0)
and
        compute_type 1 (Expected type)
-}
```

```
ct2 : String -> Type
ct2 "Integer" = Integer
ct2 "String"  = String
foo2 : (s : String) -> ct2 s
-- foo2 "Integer" = 42
```

Error:

```
{-
   |
28 | foo2 "Integer" = 42
   |                  ~~
When checking right hand side of foo2 with expected type
        ct2 "Integer"

ct2 "Integer" is not a numeric type
-}
```

```
ct3: Bool -> Bool -> Type
ct3 True True = Nat
ct3 False False = String

foo3: (a: Bool) -> (b: Bool) -> (ct3 a b)
-- foo3 True True = Z
-- foo3 False False = "Stringggg"
```

Error:

```
{-
first_class_type.idr:44:18:
   |
44 | foo3 True True = Z
   |                  ^
When checking right hand side of foo3 with expected typ
        ct3 True True

Type mismatch between
        Nat (Type of 0)
and
        ct3 True True (Expected type)

Holes: Main.foo3, Main.foo2
-}
```

```
ct4: (b: String) -> Type
ct4 "Integer" = Integer
ct4 "String"  = String
foo4: (s: String) -> ct4 s -> Integer
-- foo4 "Integer" x = x
-- foo4 "String" ss = 987
```

Error:

```
{-
   |
67 | foo4 "Integer" x = x
   |                    ^
When checking right hand side of foo4 with expected type
        Integer

Type mismatch between
        ct4 "Integer" (Type of x)
and
        Integer (Expected type)
-}
```

I have no idea why my functions do not returns types. They look similar to Idris codes but they do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type functions are not total. You can check this with `:total foo` or specifying, that the function should be total:

```
%default total
-- or
total foo : Integer -> Type
```

Only total functions are get resolved in the type checker, otherwise it may or may not run forever. If you want to stick to `Integer` and `String`, to make your functions total, you can just add a default case:

```
compute_type : Integer  -> Type
compute_type 1 = Nat
compute_type _ = String

foo : compute_type 1
foo = Z
```